# MDC for scala play framework 2.7+

Tags: logging, playframework, mdc

How can I configure MDC for play 2.7+, 2.8+?
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaLogging

Is "Marker" a replacement for MDC?

Comment: MDC is local to a thread, so is not a good fit for asynchronous code where work is performed across multiple threads. This is mentioned in the documentation linked in your question: "Markers can be extremely useful, because they can carry contextual information across threads where MDC may not be available, by using a MarkerContext as an implicit parameter to methods to provide a logging context." Did you have a more specific question about it?

Comment: Yes, how to use it? I want assign unique requestId for each request and output it to log using Logger. Don't follow how to do it...